# Answer to the question in another question

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137920/twoway-view-add-empty-space-automatically-solved) is actually an answer to few other questions and it's not actually a question itself. The answer to the question extends the answer. The solution refers to a library (probably developed by the OP) and the answer itself just shows the usage of the library.(Sorry if that sounds too confusing, just have a look at the question and you'll know)

The post is certainly useful, as seen in comments, but since it's not an actual question, it should be merged with another questions as an answer.

I was not sure of the action, so I have flagged it for moderator attention, but the flag is still pending and there's no action taken on it even after 15+ days.
I am posting it here, because I though it has been ignored. At worst it's a kind of library link spam.

Is it correct to leave the question as it is?

Comment: [Self promotion is fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers), within limits. Why don't you just edit the question to be more of a question?

Comment: @Liam Wouldn't it conflict with OP's intent or would change too much of text?

Comment: Not if your careful. I don't mean re-write the entire thing, but if you just added an answerable question into the actual question. That said (Now I'm not an android developer so maybe I'm missing something) I'm not clear what this is solving?